# How to change a user's avatar from the command line?

Tags: fedora, kde-plasma, fedora-38

I have a need to set the user's avatar at time of set-up from the command line for Fedora/KDE. Is there a way?

I have sen references to locating the faces file and changing the file. However sweeping my home directory I cannot locate it.

Comment: Please try [unix.se] instead for questions about configuring a Linux-based operating system, desktop environment, window manager etc. On-topic questions here about Fedora should be about writing code that needs to be changed specifically because it will run on a Fedora system, or about installing a programming-specific tool on Fedora (in a case where it actually matters that this is the operating system), etc.

Comment: "I have sen references to locating the faces file and changing the file. However sweeping my home directory I cannot locate it." Did you try reading those references more closely, to see if they can tell you anything about where the file is? Did you try using a search engine, for example to look for something like `fedora where is the faces file`?